# Show two WebGL animations with the same shader

Tags: javascript, webgl

I need to show two animations using WebGL on the page. Do I need to instantiate multiple shaders, or is there a way to reuse one shader? They are using the same program (so not entirely different animations). They both need to react to mouse events.

something like this

```
window.onload = function() {
    main('canvas1');
    main('canvas2');
}

function main(element) {
  // Get A WebGL context
  var canvas = document.getElementById(element);
  var gl = getWebGLContext(canvas);
  if (!gl) {
    return;
  }

  // setup GLSL program
  vertexShader = createShaderFromScriptElement(gl, "2d-vertex-shader");
  fragmentShader = createShaderFromScriptElement(gl, "2d-fragment-shader");
  program = createProgram(gl, [vertexShader, fragmentShader]);
  gl.useProgram(program);
  ...
}
```

I don't understand the derogaratory remarks. I asked a theoretical question about webgl, not particular code.

I ran this code and it works. So now all I need to know is if I can use mouse events on both. I'd be surprised if that didn't work.

Comment: Please provide more details. This doesn't explain well what is the problem and what is that you need.

Comment: [does this answer help](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26442362/webgl-javascript-object-transformations-with-multiple-objects/26444813#26444813)?

Comment: @gman Your answer did help, I didn't realize it was a link at first.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This was already answered by someone else:
[Is it possible to have two WebGL contexts on the same page?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9122361/is-it-possible-to-have-two-webgl-contexts-on-the-same-page)

WebGL cannot share resources over multiple contexts. But you can create an object with its own gl variable, and then have multiple contexts on the page. The only limit I see now is that somehow it's intensive for the system and it won't allow more than 16 concurrent contexts.