# How to get webglcontextrestored fired

Tags: javascript, html5-canvas, webgl

I want to have a fairly large number of HTML `canvas` that I draw on using  WebGL. But if I draw more than 8 or 16 or a similar, client-dependent number, earlier ones disappear.

Based on the [WebGL wiki](https://www.khronos.org/webgl/wiki/HandlingContextLost) I thought that reacting on `webglcontextlost` and `webglcontextrestored` would fix this… but it does not seem to be the case.

I essentially tried this code:

```
  canvas.addEventListener('webglcontextlost', e => {
    e.preventDefault();
  });
  canvas.addEventListener('webglcontextrestored', e => {
    render();
  });
```

with [full fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/o5967kb0/3/) available.

Do I have a coding error, or a conceptual error?

Comment: Is there anything that will make the still active ones lose their own context at some point? Otherwise I guess the UA will not restore your context. Using [this fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/4hzo1L9y/), the automatically lost contexts are *sporadically* restored on my Chrome.

Answer (score 2):

You can:t have more than 8 or 16 WebGL canvas. That's just a limit browsers put because WebGL uses lots of resources.

The best your code would do is make one fail and another re-start but I suspect most browsers don't handle that case well.

You probably don't actually want multiple WebGL canvases if you can avoid it since they can't share resources.

There are other solutions:

One is using a single canvas that doesn't scroll with the screen. Putting placeholder elements in your document and then looking where those elements are. If they are on the screen then draw a scene in the appropriate place in the canvas.

[A three.js example](https://threejs.org/examples/#webgl_multiple_elements). [A WebGL example](http://twgljs.org/examples/itemlist.html). Also [a S.O question that kind of talks about this and other solutions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33165068/how-can-we-have-display-of-same-objects-in-two-canvas-in-webgl)

Another might be [virtualizing the WebGL contexts](https://github.com/greggman/virtual-webgl) so there's really only one context. That's slower but the the various users of th canvas don't have to co-operate

Comment: Looks like something like the itemlist approach is what I need.