# two equal object on same canvas (split mode) webgl

Tags: javascript, canvas, webgl

I'm try to use the same object (a simple cube) in split screen. 
Initially I create two canvas, with two different programs and I used a same point for render twice a cube. 
Obviously didn't work and i read on this [Topic](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33165068/how-can-we-have-display-of-same-objects-in-two-canvas-in-webgl) that I can't do this way.

The answer suggest to use

> single canvas using gl.enable(gl.SCISSOR_TEST), gl.scissor and
>   gl.viewport

I'm new with this stuff and i don't understand how to do.

He suggest an example too, but is very complex and I don't understand.

My example is very simple, i just want draw this two cube(from the same points) with different projection just for see in real time the difference between different projection.

Anyone can help me?

Edit: As suggest from Gman i edit my code in this way

```
window.onload = function init() {

    canvas = document.getElementById( "gl-canvas" );

    gl = WebGLUtils.setupWebGL( canvas );
    if ( !gl ) { alert( "WebGL isn't available" ); }

   //4
    const width = gl.canvas.width;
    const height = gl.canvas.height;
    const displayWidth = gl.canvas.clientWidth;
    const displayHeight = gl.canvas.clientHeight;




 gl.clearColor( 1.0, 1.0, 1.0, 1.0 );

    gl.viewport( 0, 0, canvas.width, canvas.height );

    gl.enable(gl.DEPTH_TEST);

//
//  Load shaders and initialize attribute buffers
//
program = initShaders( gl, "vertex-shader", "fragment-shader" );
gl.useProgram( program );

colorCube();



render(0, 0, width / 2, height, displayWidth / 2, displayHeight);

// draw on right
render(width / 2, 0, width / 2, height, displayWidth / 2, displayHeight);
```

and the render function is

```
var render = function(drawX, drawY, drawWidth, drawHeight, dispWidth, dispHeight) {



eye = vec3(radius*Math.sin(phi), radius*Math.sin(theta),radius*Math.cos(phi));


gl.enable(gl.SCISSOR_TEST);
gl.viewport(drawX, drawY, drawWidth, drawHeight);
gl.scissor(drawX, drawY, drawWidth, drawHeight);

gl.clear( gl.COLOR_BUFFER_BIT | gl.DEPTH_BUFFER_BIT);


mvMatrix = lookAt(eye, at , up);
const aspect = dispWidth / dispHeight;



pMatrix = ortho(left, right, bottom, ytop, near, far);


gl.uniformMatrix4fv( modelView, false, flatten(mvMatrix) );
gl.uniformMatrix4fv( projection, false, flatten(pMatrix) );




gl.drawArrays( gl.TRIANGLES, 0, numVertices );


//requestAnimFrame(render);
```

}

if i don't remove requestAnimFrame i see the 2 cube just for a sec and after all will be delete.

Comment: What do you mean with "Obviously didn't work"? If it was obvious, why did you even try it? If it wasn't obvious, then why say it is? As for what to do: reduce your code to a [mcve] that you can add to your post. Describe what you want to do (you did that), show what you tried already (talk about all the things you tried), explain why that didn't do what you wanted it to, and then show the code you have right now so that people can comment on how to modify that code to do what you need it to do, instead.

Comment: You have a great ability to help by attacking people. Obviously it doesn't work, after reading that I can't declare 2 canvas and use the same points. For me it was the first thought, I do the same and I do it twice. I think it is superfluous to post an elementary code that does not work with a technique that I have already said is wrong (as far as I have documented). I'm not looking for someone who writes code for me, I would like to understand it (which is slightly different) and understand the technique. @Mike'Pomax'Kamermans

Comment: You seem to mistake someone telling you to please read up on how SO works, and what a good question looks like vs. what a bad question looks like, for a personal attack. That's worrisome: no one who leaves the standard "please take the tour and read our policy articles" is attacking anyone: posting to SO comes with some requirements, and not meeting those means either your question gets closed (e.g. when it's [off topic](/help/on-topic), which is not the case here) or people simply pass it over because you don't provide the detail necessary to actually help. So again, please show code.

Comment: You edited your code but you're not showing all the code. If your code works without any scissor/viewport changes then it should work with them. So first get it to work drawing a single square/cube or whatever as you had it before. Then just call it twice except set the viewport/scissor before calling it and use the size of the viewport for your calculations instead of the size of the canvas.

Comment: I'm using a https://github.com/esangel/WebGL/tree/master/Chap5 the two file orto and prespective for mix togheter. I m don't write all because is too long, i will edit again  @gman

Comment: you haven't posted all your code. The render function you posted does not use aspect at all and your projection function "ortho" uses 6 variables you haven't shown.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is nothing hard about using `gl.viewport` and `gl.scissor`

A typical WebGL program does this to render

```
gl.viewport(0, 0, gl.canvas.width, gl.canvas.height);

const aspect = gl.canvas.clientWidth / gl.canvas.clientHeight;

const projection = someProjectionFunction(fieldOfView, aspect, zNear, zFar)

... draw stuff ...
```

So, let's change that into a function that takes a projection

```
function render(drawX, drawY, drawWidth, projection) {
   gl.viewport(drawX, drawY, drawWidth, drawHeight);

   ... draw stuff ...
}
```

We can now call it like this

```
const width = gl.canvas.width;
const height = gl.canvas.height;
const displayWidth = gl.canvas.clientWidth;
const displayHeight = gl.canvas.clientHeight;

const aspect = displayWidth / displayHeight;

const projection = someProjectionFunction(fieldOfView, aspect, zNear, zFar)

// draw on left
render(0, 0, width / 2, height, projection);

// draw on right
render(width / 2, 0, width / 2, height, projection);
```

That already handles the `viewport` part and will work. All that's left is the scissor

```
function render(drawX, drawY, drawWidth, drawHeight, projection) {
   gl.viewport(drawX, drawY, drawWidth, drawHeight);
   gl.scissor(drawX, drawY, drawWidth, drawHeight);
   gl.enable(gl.SCISSOR_TEST);

   ... draw stuff using projection ...
}
```

Now go update it pass in more info like a different projection or a different camera

```js
const gl = document.querySelector('canvas').getContext('webgl');
const m4 = twgl.m4;

const vs = `
attribute vec4 position;
uniform mat4 matrix;
void main() {
  gl_Position = matrix * position;
}
`;
const fs = `
precision mediump float;
void main() {
  gl_FragColor = vec4(1, 0, 0, 1);
}
`;

const program = twgl.createProgram(gl, [vs, fs]);
const posLoc = gl.getAttribLocation(program, 'position');
const matLoc = gl.getUniformLocation(program, 'matrix');

const buf = gl.createBuffer();
gl.bindBuffer(gl.ARRAY_BUFFER, buf);
gl.bufferData(gl.ARRAY_BUFFER, new Float32Array([
  -1, -1, -1, 
   1, -1, -1,
  -1,  1, -1,
   1,  1, -1,
  -1, -1,  1, 
   1, -1,  1,
  -1,  1,  1,
   1,  1,  1,
]), gl.STATIC_DRAW);

const indices = gl.createBuffer();
gl.bindBuffer(gl.ELEMENT_ARRAY_BUFFER, indices);
gl.bufferData(gl.ELEMENT_ARRAY_BUFFER, new Uint16Array([
  0, 1, 1, 3, 3, 2, 2, 0,
  4, 5, 5, 7, 7, 6, 6, 4,
  0, 4, 1, 5, 3, 7, 2, 6,
]), gl.STATIC_DRAW);

function renderLoop(time) {
  time *= 0.001;
  
  function render(drawX, drawY, drawWidth, drawHeight, projection) {
     gl.viewport(drawX, drawY, drawWidth, drawHeight);
     gl.scissor(drawX, drawY, drawWidth, drawHeight);
     gl.enable(gl.SCISSOR_TEST);
     
     gl.clear(gl.COLOR_BUFFER_BIT);
     
     let mat = m4.copy(projection);
     mat = m4.translate(mat, [0, 0, -5]);
     mat = m4.rotateZ(mat, time);
     mat = m4.rotateX(mat, time * 0.5);
     gl.useProgram(program);
     gl.uniformMatrix4fv(matLoc, false, mat);
     gl.enableVertexAttribArray(posLoc);
     gl.bindBuffer(gl.ARRAY_BUFFER, buf);
     gl.vertexAttribPointer(posLoc, 3, gl.FLOAT, false, 0, 0);
     gl.bindBuffer(gl.ELEMENT_ARRAY_BUFFER, indices);
     gl.drawElements(gl.LINES, 24, gl.UNSIGNED_SHORT, 0);
  }

  const width = gl.canvas.width;
  const height = gl.canvas.height;
  const displayWidth = gl.canvas.clientWidth;
  const displayHeight = gl.canvas.clientHeight;

  // draw on left
  {
    const drawX = 0;
    const drawY = 0;
    const drawWidth = width / 2;
    const drawHeight = height;
    const dispWidth = displayWidth / 2;
    const dispHeight = displayHeight;
    
    const fieldOfView = 45 * Math.PI / 180;
    const aspect = dispWidth / dispHeight;
    const zNear = 0.1;
    const zFar = 20;
    const projection = m4.perspective(fieldOfView, aspect, zNear, zFar)

    gl.clearColor(1, 1, 0, 1);
    render(drawX, drawY, drawWidth, drawHeight, projection);
  }

  // draw on right
  {
    const drawX = width / 2;
    const drawY = 0;
    const drawWidth = width / 2;
    const drawHeight = height;
    const dispWidth = displayWidth / 2;
    const dispHeight = displayHeight;
  
    const aspect = dispWidth / dispHeight;
    const top = 2;
    const bottom = -top;
    const right = top * aspect;
    const left = -right;
    const zNear = 0.1;
    const zFar = 20;
    
    const projection = m4.ortho(left, right, bottom, top, zNear, zFar);
    gl.clearColor(0, 1, 1, 1);
    render(drawX, drawY, drawWidth, drawHeight, projection);
  }

  requestAnimationFrame(renderLoop);
}
requestAnimationFrame(renderLoop);
```

```html
<canvas></canvas>
<script src="https://twgljs.org/dist/4.x/twgl-full.min.js"></script>
```

Example using your book's example

```js
"use strict";

var canvas;
var gl;

var NumVertices  = 36;

var pointsArray = [];
var colorsArray = [];

var vertices = [
    vec4(-0.5, -0.5,  1.5, 1.0),
    vec4(-0.5,  0.5,  1.5, 1.0),
    vec4(0.5,  0.5,  1.5, 1.0),
    vec4(0.5, -0.5,  1.5, 1.0),
    vec4(-0.5, -0.5, 0.5, 1.0),
    vec4(-0.5,  0.5, 0.5, 1.0),
    vec4(0.5,  0.5, 0.5, 1.0),
    vec4( 0.5, -0.5, 0.5, 1.0)
];

var vertexColors = [
    vec4( 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 1.0 ),  // black
    vec4( 1.0, 0.0, 0.0, 1.0 ),  // red
    vec4( 1.0, 1.0, 0.0, 1.0 ),  // yellow
    vec4( 0.0, 1.0, 0.0, 1.0 ),  // green
    vec4( 0.0, 0.0, 1.0, 1.0 ),  // blue
    vec4( 1.0, 0.0, 1.0, 1.0 ),  // magenta
    vec4( 0.0, 1.0, 1.0, 1.0 ),  // cyan
    vec4( 1.0, 1.0, 1.0, 1.0 ),  // white
];


var near = 0.3;
var far = 3.0;
var radius = 4.0;
var theta  = 0.0;
var phi    = 0.0;
var dr = 5.0 * Math.PI/180.0;

var  fovy = 45.0;  // Field-of-view in Y direction angle (in degrees)
var  aspect;       // Viewport aspect ratio

var mvMatrix, pMatrix;
var modelView, projection;
var eye;
const at = vec3(0.0, 0.0, 0.0);
const up = vec3(0.0, 1.0, 0.0);

function quad(a, b, c, d) {
     pointsArray.push(vertices[a]);
     colorsArray.push(vertexColors[a]);
     pointsArray.push(vertices[b]);
     colorsArray.push(vertexColors[a]);
     pointsArray.push(vertices[c]);
     colorsArray.push(vertexColors[a]);
     pointsArray.push(vertices[a]);
     colorsArray.push(vertexColors[a]);
     pointsArray.push(vertices[c]);
     colorsArray.push(vertexColors[a]);
     pointsArray.push(vertices[d]);
     colorsArray.push(vertexColors[a]);
}


function colorCube()
{
    quad( 1, 0, 3, 2 );
    quad( 2, 3, 7, 6 );
    quad( 3, 0, 4, 7 );
    quad( 6, 5, 1, 2 );
    quad( 4, 5, 6, 7 );
    quad( 5, 4, 0, 1 );
}


function init() {

    canvas = document.getElementById( "gl-canvas" );

    gl = WebGLUtils.setupWebGL( canvas );
    if ( !gl ) { alert( "WebGL isn't available" ); }

    gl.viewport( 0, 0, canvas.width, canvas.height );

    aspect =  canvas.width/canvas.height;

    gl.clearColor( 1.0, 1.0, 1.0, 1.0 );

    gl.enable(gl.DEPTH_TEST);


    //
    //  Load shaders and initialize attribute buffers
    //
    var program = initShaders( gl, "vertex-shader", "fragment-shader" );
    gl.useProgram( program );

    colorCube();

    var cBuffer = gl.createBuffer();
    gl.bindBuffer( gl.ARRAY_BUFFER, cBuffer );
    gl.bufferData( gl.ARRAY_BUFFER, flatten(colorsArray), gl.STATIC_DRAW );

    var vColor = gl.getAttribLocation( program, "vColor" );
    gl.vertexAttribPointer( vColor, 4, gl.FLOAT, false, 0, 0 );
    gl.enableVertexAttribArray( vColor);

    var vBuffer = gl.createBuffer();
    gl.bindBuffer( gl.ARRAY_BUFFER, vBuffer );
    gl.bufferData( gl.ARRAY_BUFFER, flatten(pointsArray), gl.STATIC_DRAW );

    var vPosition = gl.getAttribLocation( program, "vPosition" );
    gl.vertexAttribPointer( vPosition, 4, gl.FLOAT, false, 0, 0 );
    gl.enableVertexAttribArray( vPosition );

    modelView = gl.getUniformLocation( program, "modelView" );
    projection = gl.getUniformLocation( program, "projection" );
// buttons for viewing parameters

    document.getElementById("Button1").onclick = function(){near  *= 1.1; far *= 1.1;};
    document.getElementById("Button2").onclick = function(){near *= 0.9; far *= 0.9;};
    document.getElementById("Button3").onclick = function(){radius *= 2.0;};
    document.getElementById("Button4").onclick = function(){radius *= 0.5;};
    document.getElementById("Button5").onclick = function(){theta += dr;};
    document.getElementById("Button6").onclick = function(){theta -= dr;};
    document.getElementById("Button7").onclick = function(){phi += dr;};
    document.getElementById("Button8").onclick = function(){phi -= dr;};

    render();
}


var render = function(){

    function renderScene(drawX, drawY, drawWidth, drawHeight, pMatrix) {
      gl.enable(gl.SCISSOR_TEST);
      gl.viewport(drawX, drawY, drawWidth, drawHeight);
      gl.scissor(drawX, drawY, drawWidth, drawHeight);
      
      gl.clear( gl.COLOR_BUFFER_BIT | gl.DEPTH_BUFFER_BIT);

      eye = vec3(radius*Math.sin(theta)*Math.cos(phi),
          radius*Math.sin(theta)*Math.sin(phi), radius*Math.cos(theta));
      mvMatrix = lookAt(eye, at , up);

      gl.uniformMatrix4fv( modelView, false, flatten(mvMatrix) );
      gl.uniformMatrix4fv( projection, false, flatten(pMatrix) );

      gl.drawArrays( gl.TRIANGLES, 0, NumVertices );
    }
    
    const width = gl.canvas.width;
    const height = gl.canvas.height;
    const displayWidth = gl.canvas.clientWidth;
    const displayHeight = gl.canvas.clientHeight;

    // draw left
    {
      const dispWidth = displayWidth / 2;
      const dispHeight = displayHeight;
      const aspect = dispWidth / dispHeight;
      const pMatrix = perspective(fovy, aspect, near, far);
      gl.clearColor(0.1, 0.1, 0.1, 1);
      renderScene(0, 0, width / 2, height, pMatrix);
    }
    
    // draw right
    {
      const dispWidth = displayWidth / 2;
      const dispHeight = displayHeight;
      const aspect = dispWidth / dispHeight;
      const top = 1;
      const bottom = -top;
      const right = top * aspect;
      const left = -right;
      const pMatrix = ortho(left, right, bottom, top,  near, far);
      gl.clearColor(0.2, 0.2, 0.2, 1);
      renderScene(width / 2, 0, width / 2, height, pMatrix);
    }

    requestAnimFrame(render);
}

init();
```

```html
<p> </p>
<button id = "Button1">Increase Z</button>
<button id = "Button2">Decrease Z</button>
<button id = "Button3">Increase R</button>
<button id = "Button4">Decrease R</button>

<p> </p>
<button id = "Button5">Increase theta</button>
<button id = "Button6">Decrease theta</button>
<button id = "Button7">Increase phi</button>
<button id = "Button8">Decrease phi</button>
<p> </p>


<script id="vertex-shader" type="x-shader/x-vertex">
attribute  vec4 vPosition;
attribute  vec4 vColor;
varying vec4 fColor;
uniform mat4 modelView;
uniform mat4 projection;
void main() 
{
    gl_Position = projection*modelView*vPosition;
    fColor = vColor;
} 
</script>

<script id="fragment-shader" type="x-shader/x-fragment">
precision mediump float;
varying vec4 fColor;
void
main()
{
    gl_FragColor = fColor;
}
</script>

<script src="https://esangel.github.io/WebGL/Common/webgl-utils.js"></script>
<script src="https://esangel.github.io/WebGL/Common/initShaders.js"></script>
<script src="https://esangel.github.io/WebGL/Common/MV.js"></script>

<canvas id="gl-canvas" width="400" height="100"></canvas>
```

Comment: thank you for reply. I tried to edit as you told me but I didn't work. I also added some code in question to show the changes made

Comment: If you are going to clear you need to clear after enable and setting the scissor otherwise you will clear the entire canvas. Added working example

Comment: I did. I try to remove the requestAnimFrame(render); and i see the cube, but i can't use a button and other stuff... I will edit the code with new edit

Comment: changed the code to take a projection, use a perspective projection on the left and a orthographic projection on the right.

Comment: why if I use a requestAnimFrame(render); all image disappeared?

Comment: There is no such function `requestAnimFrame`. Maybe you meant `requestAnimationFrame`? The code above is using `requestAnimationFrame`. We can't debug your code unless you post it in your question

Comment: i tested you code on https://codepen.io/anon/pen/dLpvBM?editors=1010 and seems dont run..maybe it's my problem.. Thanks so much for your interested!