# setContext of canvas is undeined

Tags: google-chrome, webgl

I want to set context of canvas1 to canvas2.
I saw here - https://developers.whatwg.org/the-canvas-element.html#dom-canvas-setcontext
that setContext() is supported but I get an error of undefined function in chrome.

```
      var canvas1 = document.getElementById("myCanvas1");
      var canvas2 = document.getElementById("myCanvas2");
      ctx1 = canvas1.getContext("webgl");
      var gl = canvas2.setContext(ctx1);
```

why it happened?
how can I set context of canvas from another canvas's context?

Answer (score 1):

Currently this feature is not supported by any [browser](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLCanvasElement#Browser_compatibility).

The whatwg documentation is about standards, but not all the standards are currently supported by browsers. I recommend you to check [caniuse](http://caniuse.com) and [MDN](http://developers.mozilla.org) to verify the actual support.

Comment: what's exactly your purpose? Do you want your `canvas2` to be an exact copy of `canvas1`?

Comment: I want to create canvas 2 with the same context as canvas 1, but then each one of them will act standalone.
Not mirror 1 in 2.

Comment: That's a contradiction, if they share the same context (same frame buffer, same render buffer) how could they act differently?
I don't think that there is a workaround, what you want to do seems to be really tight coupled with the DOM implementation.

Comment: I have a texture that belong to canvas1, when Im trying to render it from canvas2 I get an errro that "object not belong to this context".
So Im trying to find a workaround - any idea?

Comment: This may be of help: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9122361/is-it-possible-to-have-two-webgl-contexts-on-the-same-page